# how to remove numbers and parentheses from a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, numpy, apply

I have a dataframe with approx 300 rows as follows

```
    Country
0   Bolivia (Plurinational State of)
1   Switzerland17
2   United States
```

I have to transform it to:

```
    Country
0   Bolivia
1   Switzerland
2   United States
```

In the modified data frame words in parentheses and numerical digits are removed.
Please help me.

Comment: Try `[\d()].*` replace nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment I got the answer:

```
import re
def Clean_names(name): 
    if re.search('\(.*|\d.*', name): 
        pos = re.search('\(.*|\d.*', name).start()  
        return name[:pos] 
    else:  
        return name
df['Country'] = df['Country'].apply(Clean_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Name']=df['Name'].transform(lambda value:value.split('(')[0])
```

Explanation: apply transform() over 'name' & split the values using '('. Take the 1st value after applying the split

Comment: Lambda function will not search for numbers.